Unit-Root Asymptotics
I am using the book "Time-series-based econometrics" by Hatanaka to learn about asymptotic theory of unit roots. However, it is quite technical, so I am also using Hamilton's "Time Series Analysis" alongside it. There is an example in Hatanaka's book about the Dickey-Fuller estimator when the data generating process is $y_t = \alpha + \rho y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{t}$, where $ \varepsilon_{t} \sim N(0,1) $, with true parameters being $ \alpha_0, \rho_0 $. Assuming that $ \rho_0 = 1 $ and $ \alpha_0 \neq 0 $, it then follows that the ordinary least squares estimator $ \hat{\rho} $ satisfies
$$ T^{3/2}(\hat{\rho} - 1) \to N(0, 12\mu_0^2) $$
I understand the basics of asymptotic theory, so I made my attempt, but I don't reach something similar to what's in the book. I do get a normal distribution, but it's not the same as the one in the book. Additionally, I ran some simulations, and everything indicates that the book is correct. Could someone please help me see where my mistake is?
$\textbf{Attempt}$
Let's assume the data generating process is
$ y_t = \mu + y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t = \mu t + \sum \varepsilon_t = \mu t + \zeta_t $
(where we assume $ y_0 = 0 $), and that the following specification is used:
$ \Delta y_t = \mu + \gamma y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t. $
The matrix form of the OLS estimators is given by:
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\mu} \\
\hat{\gamma}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
T & \sum y_{t-1} \\
\sum y_{t-1} & \sum y_{t-1}^2
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum \Delta y_t \\
\sum y_{t-1} \Delta y_t
\end{bmatrix} =
$
$
= \frac{1}{T \sum y_{t-1}^2 - (\sum y_{t-1})^2} \begin{bmatrix}
\sum y_{t-1}^2 & -\sum y_{t-1} \\
-\sum y_{t-1} & T
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum \Delta y_t \\
\sum y_{t-1} \Delta y_t
\end{bmatrix}.
$
Thus,
$
\boxed{\hat{\mu} = \dfrac{\sum y_{t-1}^2 \sum \Delta y_t - \sum y_{t-1} \sum y_{t-1} \Delta y_t}{T \sum y_{t-1}^2 - \left(\sum y_{t-1}\right)^2}.}
$
$
\boxed{\hat{\gamma} = \dfrac{T \sum y_{t-1} \Delta y_t - \sum y_{t-1} \sum \Delta y_t}{T \sum y_{t-1}^2 - \left(\sum y_{t-1}\right)^2}.}
$
In this document, we will obtain the asymptotic behavior of the estimator $ \hat{\gamma} $. To do this, we first develop the necessary sums, remembering that from this point, we assume we know the true process.

$\sum y_{t-1} \Delta y_t = \mu^2 \sum (t-1) + \mu \sum (t-1) \varepsilon_t + \mu \sum \zeta_{t-1} + \sum \zeta_{t-1} \varepsilon_t.$
$\sum y_{t-1} = \mu \sum (t-1) + \sum \zeta_{t-1}.$
$\sum \Delta y_t = T \mu + \sum \varepsilon_t.$
$\sum y_{t-1}^2 = \mu^2 \sum (t-1)^2 + 2 \mu \sum (t-1) \zeta_{t-1} + \sum \zeta_{t-1}^2.$

With the above, the expression for $ \hat{\gamma}$ becomes
\begin{align*}
\hat{\gamma} = \dfrac{T \mu^2 \sum (t-1) + \mu T \sum (t-1) \varepsilon_t + \mu T \sum \zeta_{t-1} + T \sum \zeta_{t-1} \varepsilon_t - T \mu^2 \sum (t-1) - \mu \sum (t-1) \sum \varepsilon_t - T \mu \sum \zeta_{t-1} - \sum \zeta_{t-1} \sum \varepsilon_t}{T \mu^2 \sum (t-1)^2 + 2T \mu \sum (t-1) \zeta_{t-1} + T \sum \zeta_{t-1}^2 - \mu^2 (\sum (t-1))^2 - (\sum \zeta_{t-1})^2 - 2 \mu \sum (t-1) \sum \zeta_{t-1}}.
\end{align*}
$
= \dfrac{T \mu \sum (t-1) \varepsilon_t + T \sum \zeta_{t-1} \varepsilon_t - \mu \sum (t-1) \sum \varepsilon_t - \sum \zeta_{t-1} \sum \varepsilon_t}{\frac{T^4 \mu^2}{12} - \frac{T^2 \mu^2}{12} + 2T \mu \sum (t-1) \zeta_{t-1} + T \sum \zeta_{t-1}^2 - 2 \mu \sum (t-1) \sum \zeta_{t-1}}.
$
Notice that the numerator is $ O_p(T^{5/2}) $ and the denominator is $O(T^4) $, which means the estimator is $ O_p(T^{-3/2}) $. Now, applying what we know about the orders of convergence of the numerator and denominator, we see what this estimator converges to:
$$
T^{3/2} \hat{\gamma} = \dfrac{\mu T^{-3/2} \sum t \varepsilon_t - \left(\dfrac{\mu}{2}\right) T^{-1/2} \sum \varepsilon_t}{\dfrac{\mu^2}{12}}
= \frac{12 T^{-3/2} \sum t \varepsilon_t - 6 T^{-1/2} \sum \varepsilon_t}{\mu} \stackrel{a}{=}
$$
$$
\stackrel{a}{=} \frac{12\sigma\left[\omega(1) - \int_0^1 \omega(r) dr\right] - 6\sigma\omega(1)}{\mu}.
$$
This basically tells us that the estimator is asymptotically normal.

I would check whether Hayashi or Hamilton have any references related to that statement about $12 \mu_{0}^2 $. Also, check the appendices of Hamilton. He often has a lot of derivations in the appendices of his chapters.

Maybe unify notation of $\alpha$ and $\mu$

It would appear (but check), that your case is, or is close to, Hamilton's book, Case 3, pp. 495-497, although he does not use the differenced dependent variable (his specification is his eq. 17.4.14).
If indeed this is the case, Hamilton gives (implicitly, invert the matrix $Q$ in eq. 17.4.45 and .46 ), the asymptotic variance of the centered and scaled estimate of the slope coefficient as $12/\mu^2$, i.e. $\mu^2$ divides $12$, it does not multiply it.

Indeed, it is the same case and it is probably a typographical error in Hatanaka's book, but my problem is that the expression I arrive at is not even similar.

@Haus Perhaps because you implement a different estimating equation? Hamilton uses the dependent variable as-is, while you use it in first-differences, while you both use the same right-hand side.
